# Webdriverio Typescript TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I am facing an issue with WebdriverIO and Typescript where I keep getting compilation errors. I tried importing $ and $$ explicitly in the test files but it still doesn't work

tsconfig.json

```
  "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "target": "ES6",
      "types": [
        //"@wdio/sync",
        "mocha", 
        "node",
        "webdriverio",
        "webdriverio/async"
        //"@wdio/globals/types"
        ],
      "strict": true,
      "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"],
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "isolatedModules": true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
      "strictNullChecks": true,
      "strictFunctionTypes": true,
      "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
      "noImplicitThis": true,
      "alwaysStrict": true,
      "noUnusedLocals": true,
      "noUnusedParameters": true,
      "noImplicitReturns": true,
      "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "pretty": true,
      "outDir": "./build",
      "module": "commonjs",
  },
  
  "include": [
    "./test/**/*.spec.ts",
   // "./wdio.conf.js",
    "./pageObjects/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules/**/*"]
}
```

package.json

```
  "@wdio/junit-reporter": "^8.16.3",
  "@wdio/local-runner": "^8.16.6",
  "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service": "^8.15.0",
  "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^8.16.3",
  "@wdio/sync": "^7.27.0",
  "@wdio/types": "^8.16.7",
  "@wdio/utils": "^8.16.10",
```

> ERROR @wdio/utils:shim: TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
> test/login.ts(17,9): error TS2592: Cannot find name '$'. Do you need to install type definitions for jQuery? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/jquery` and then add 'jquery' to the types field in your tsconfig.
> [0-0] test/login.ts(24,21): error TS2592: Cannot find name '$'. Do you need to install type definitions for jQuery? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/jquery` and then add 'jquery' to the types field in your tsconfig.
> [0-0] test/login.ts(30,5): error TS2592: Cannot find name '$'. Do you need to install type definitions for jQuery? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/jquery` and then add 'jquery' to the types field in your tsconfig.
> [0-0] test/login.ts(35,5): error TS2592: Cannot find name '$'. Do you need to install type definitions for jQuery? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/jquery` and then add 'jquery' to the types field in your tsconfig.
> [0-0] test/login.ts(40,5): error TS2592: Cannot find name '$'. Do you need to install type definitions for jQuery? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/jquery` and then add 'jquery' to the types field in your tsconfig.
> [0-0] test/login.ts(41,5): error TS2592: Cannot find name '$'. Do you need to install type definitions for jQuery? T

Answer (score 0):

With WebdriverIO v8, the typescript setup was changed a bit.
You can check it here https://webdriver.io/docs/typescript#framework-types

All the wdio typings would be available under `@wdio/globals/types` and then you have to add framework specific types for `jasmine/mocha`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "types": ["node", "@wdio/globals/types", "@wdio/mocha-framework"]
    }
}
```